# How to filter object with specified type in generic collections in VB

Tags: vb.net, generic-list

given the following class structures:

- Class Base {id}
- Class Derived1 : Base {}
- Class Derived2 : Base {}
- Class MyList : System.Collection.Generic.List(Of Base)
- Class Consumer { list as MyList }

(edit: there will be more than 2 derived classes, I listed out only 2 for simplicity)

I add the following property to MyList, trying to answer questions like "find out the number of elements with specified type, say Derived1, inside MyList?"

```
Public Overloads ReadOnly Property Count(ByVal objType As System.Type) As Integer
    Get
        Dim cnt As Integer = 0
        For Each o As Object In Me
            If (o IsNot Nothing) And (o.GetType.Equals(objType)) Then cnt += 1
        Next
        Return cnt
    End Get
End Property
```

Q1: Are there anything to improve? If yes, please advise.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

In case you use .NET 3.5 you could use Linq:

```
Dim myList As MyList;
...
Dim count = myList.OfType(Of Derived1).Count();
```

No need add the property at all.

Comment: Thanks for information, but what if the question is "Please select from MyList with type Derived1, and also ID = 'abc'" (id field is from Base class)? (ID of Derived1 may be equal to ID of Derived2), and (MyList has no checking of uniqueness of 'ID' field)